# Copying a file to new folders as they are created

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get excel to create a folder based on the value entered in column A and copy a document into that newly created folder. I have the copy function commented out for the moment.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Z As Long
    Dim xVal As String
    On Error Resume Next
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Z = 1 To Target.Count
        If Target(Z).Value > 0 Then
            Call MakeFolders
            'Call FileCopy
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub MakeFolders()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim maxRows As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Set sht = Worksheets("NPI")
    Set StartCell = Range("A2")
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    LastColumn = 1
    sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select
    Set Rng = Selection
    maxRows = Rng.Rows.Count
    For c = 1 To 1
        r = 1
        Do While r <= maxRows
            If Len(Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                MkDir (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c))
                On Error Resume Next
            End If
            r = r + 1
        Loop
    Next c
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
End Sub

'Sub FileCopy()
    'Dim SourcePath As String
    'Dim DestinationPath As String
    'SourcePath = "C:\Users\xxxxx.xxxxx\Documents\Directory\NPI\test.txt"
    'DestinationPath = "C:\Users\xxxxx.xxxxx\Documents\Directory\NPI\NP10001\test.txt"
    'FileCopy SourcePath, DestinationPath
'End Sub
```

I run into a problem with the destination, is there a way I can make it call the Mkdir folder? Even the most recent folder would be fine.

I tried naming a directory and manually moving files out, but the whole sub isn't worth doing unless that part is done automatically

Comment: 1) change Set StartCell = Range("A2") to Set StartCell = sht.Range("A2"),    


2) Is better to use  CountLarge property and not Count, eg sht.Rows.Count => sht.Rows.CountLarge  3) Don't use Selection do refer to an object, use instead:  Set Rng = sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim folderPath As String, sourceFilePath As String
    Dim folderName As String, destinationFilePath As String
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Replace "Sheet1" with your sheet name
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, ws.Columns("A")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Intersect(Target, ws.Columns("A"))
            If cell.Value > 0 Then
                ' Get the folder path using the workbook's path
                folderPath = wb.Path
                
                ' Get the folder name based on the cell value
                folderName = CStr(cell.Value)
                
                ' Create the folder if it doesn't already exist
                If Len(Dir(folderPath & "\" & folderName, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                    MkDir folderPath & "\" & folderName
                End If
                
                'copy file
                sourceFilePath = "C:\Users\xxxxx.xxxxx\Documents\Directory\NPI\test.txt"
                destinationFilePath = folderPath & "\" & folderName & "\" & "test.txt"
                FileCopy sourceFilePath, destinationFilePath
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
    
    ' Clean up
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked beautifully.